# Was Jayne from Canton?

Tags: firefly

The song "The Hero of Canton" contains the following lines:

> He saw the Mudders' lament
>   And he saw the magistrate taking
>   Every dollar and leaving five cents
>   So he said, "You can't do that to my people"

The words "my people" made me wonder - was Jayne originally from Canton before he robbed the magistrate and fled? Was there really any way in which the mudders of Canton were "his people", or was that just part of the myth?

<sub>Please mark spoilers from any episodes beyond *Out of Gas*; I'm still in the middle of my first watch of *Firefly*!</sub>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Probably not.

[Jayne](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Jayne_Cobb)'s birthplace [hasn't been revealed](http://www.fireflyfans.net/mthread.aspx?tid=18459).

However, several pieces of dialogue from *[Jaynestown](http://firefly.shriftweb.org/scripts/104.shtml)*  imply that he isn't from Canton.

> JAYNE
>   Oh, listen, Mal -- I was in Canton a few 
>   years back, I might have made me a few 
>   enemies thereabouts.
>
> ...
>
> JAYNE
>   Look, Mal, I got no ruttin' idea. I was
>   here a few years back, like I said. Pulled
>   a second-story, stole a lot of scratch from
>   the magistrate up on the hill. But things
>   went way South. I had to hightail it.
>   They don't...put you on a pedestal in town
>   square for that.
>
> ...
>
> JAYNE
>   Uh...I'm no good with words. Don't...don't use
>   'em much, myself. 
>   (crowd chuckles) 
>   But I want to thank you all for being here, and
>   for thinking so much of me... Far as I see it,
>   **you people** been given the shortest end of the
>   stick ever been offered a human soul in this
>   crap-hill 'verse....But you took that end...
>   well, you took it. And that's... well, I guess 
>   that's something.

He also doesn't react when Wash insults the town. Knowing Jayne's general attitude, he probably would if he actually came from there.

> WASH
>   We gotta go to the crappy town where I'm the hero!

In the episode, the townspeople are completely wrong about Jayne. They turn his random, unintentional actions into an act of purposeful altruism. The "his people" portion is likely them just exaggerating Jayne into a typical folk-hero.

Comment: The implication of the story is that they've turned Jayne into a hero by completely screwing up his story; most likely he went into Canton under cover as part of the theft.

Answer (score 8):

I think he tried to steal from the magistrate and dropped all the money getting away. He doesn't seem to know anybody there except for his ex-partner. He also seems to have a mother who knits for him embarrassing hats and she isn't mentioned there so I don't think that is where he comes from.

Comment: The hat is awesome.  I own that hat too.

Comment: That is a shrewd hat.